# Waswasa about purity of clothes

Tags: taharah

Assalamwalikum. Is it necessary to squeeze clothes after washing under running water (under shower or hand shower)?

Comment: https://www.muftisays.com/forums/27-sharing-portal/13694-washing-machine-and-hanafi-madhab.html

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Washing in Islam is defined as what is commonly or conventionally known as washing. There's nor restriction or specific definition.

The squeezing may either be necessary to add more water remove remaining traces of  najasah or in order to rapidly drying clothes.